# Mouse - Motion Listener not working

Tags: java, mouse, mousemotionlistener

I'm a newbie here. I have a code here from which I would like to change the text of a JLabel to that of the position of a moving - mouse. Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Draw extends JFrame{

    int x;
    int y;

    String positions = "Positions: " + x + ", " + y;
    JLabel positionsOnFrame = new JLabel(positions);

    public class AL implements MouseMotionListener {

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();

        }


        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            positions += " dragged.";
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public Draw() {
        setTitle("Title");
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        addMouseMotionListener(new AL());
        add(positionsOnFrame);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Draw();
    }
}
```

Side problem: The JFrame doesn't turn black as well even though I have set the color to be black from the constructor.

Any solution to the mouse problem? Nothing happens! The values are just set to 0! (I haven't initialized them, they're just automatically set to 0!).
Help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: For the color issue do this: getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me the solution, but why do we have to call getContentPane() in order to set the background? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, uninitialized integers (such as x and y) are given a default value of zero. But it's not good practice to rely on this; best to explicitly initialize their values even if still zero.

Next, your mouseMoved() callback is in-fact getting called. But it's not updating the text of your 'positionsOnFrame' label, it's only updating the x and y coordinates. Just because you created the label with a String (positions), doesn't mean the label's text will automatically change whenever that String is changed. You have to change the text of the label accordingly. So adding positionsOnFrame.setText("Positions: " + x + "," + y); inside your mouseMoved() callback will fix that part.

Finally, change the color of the frame's content pane instead of the frame directly: getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! You're the best! Thank you so much! But... why doesn't the setBackground(Color.BLACK); work without calling the getContentPane()?

Comment: That's because the content pane is overlayed on top of the JFrame. See How to Use Root Panes for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        positionsOnFrame.setText("Positions: " + x +", " + y);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

and for the background color this should work.

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

The String `positions` will not change each time the `x` and `y` change. The value will stay with what `x` and `y` were when you assigned it originally.

For example

```
String s = "hello";

    String t = s;

    System.out.println(t);

    s = "bye";

    System.out.println(t);
```

will print `hello` both times

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! However, could you explain it to me why my code didn't work and what was the bug in my code? EDIT: Just saw the edit you did, thanks for taking the time to explain!

Comment: See the last part of my answer for the reason it wasn't working.